# Lange Nacht vs. kurze Nacht

Tags: word-usage, difference

Wenn jemand erst sehr spät ins Bett gegangen ist, weil er hatte arbeiten müssen oder gefeiert hatte, und dann übernächtigt ist, sagt er:

> Ich hatte eine kurze Nacht. (andeutend, dass die Schlafzeit kurz war)

oder

> Ich hatte eine lange Nacht. (andeutend, dass seine nächtliche Tätigkeit lange dauerte)

Ich meine, beide Formulierungen in diesem Kontext bereits gehört zu haben. Frage: **Welche und warum ist zu bevorzugen?**

Wenn jemand sagt:

> Ich hatte eine kurze Nacht.

bedeutet das eher, dass er spät ins Bett gegangen ist, oder dass er sehr früh aufgestanden ist?

Comment: Does it matter? No way to tell, really, but he certainly didn't get much sleep.

Comment: @Ingmar: "Ich hatte eine lange Nacht und habe deshalb am Folgetag bis 15 Uhr geschlafen." would convey to me that the person did get much sleep, just later than usual.

Comment: True, but you'd need to add that bit of additional info. "War 'ne lange Nacht gestern" means you're (rightfully) tired.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aus meiner Sicht ist

> Ich hatte eine kurze Nacht.

lediglich ein Hinweis auf die absolute Dauer des Schlafs. Das kann bedeuten, dass der Sprecher *später* ins Bett ging als gewöhnlich, dass er *früher* aufstand oder dass sein Schlaf *unterbrochen* wurde. Alle, die Kinder haben, kennen das ;-)

> Ich hatte eine lange Nacht.

wird gelegentlich benutzt um anzugeben, das der Sprecher später ins Bett kam als gewöhnlich. Häufiger, zumindest aus meiner Sicht, ist dagegen die Formulierung

> Es war ein langer Abend.

(Dabei könnten allerdings auch regionale Unterschiede eine Rolle spielen.)

Comment: +1 Auch wenn die Kinder krank waren und man nicht vor 3 Uhr ins Bett gekommen ist, würde ich am nächsten Tag trotzdem nie sagen, ich hatte eine lange Nacht. Eventuell ist es regional, aber bei uns würde ich eine *lange Nacht* immer mit etwas Positivem wie Party oder Weggehen verbinden.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience,

> lange Nacht

is generally used meaning that the day(-time activity) was longer than usual. It might be working late, it might be party until late at night, or simply, as for example in

> lange Nacht der Museen

that a place is open longer than normal.

> Kurze Nacht

in contrast (in my experience, still) is used when you had to rise early, or did not get enough sleep.